# Is there a proverb for "Don't ask a mother how her child is, due to her motherly bond she would be most inclined to remark he is the best"

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests, proverb-requests

Is there a idiom/proverb for "Don't ask a mother how her child is, due to her motherly bond she would be most prone/inclined to remark he is the best in the world" even when he is a brat in eyes of others (outsiders).

Comment: In Italian "ogni scarrafone è bello a mamma sua" (*scarrafone* is an ugly-looking person)

Comment: Is there a proverb or idiom that is used in your native language? Have you tried WordReference?

Comment: Hmm, there is something similar, along the lines of "_to X everything is Y_" or "_to X even Y is Z_" but I can't really recall it properly. Maybe it rings a bell for someone else

Comment: Yes there is "Ours is always The deary (mollycoddle), others is always The brat (miscreant, Dennis the Menace)"

Comment: Please don't accept answers so quickly. Give other people a chance to post their suggestions. Not even 30 minutes have gone by. You can always accept an answer later or tomorrow even. This question will probably prove to be very popular if users think their answers will be appropriate.

Comment: There's an Oriental saying "To its mother, a crow's baby is the cutest."

Comment: A bit in line with @Kris suggestion, in Turkish you could say "_To a raven mother, her chick looks like a hawk_"  and I think I heard some variant of that with geese and swans

Comment: Your question made me think of B.B. King and what his take on the subject might be: ["Nobody loves me but my Mother, and she could be jivin' too."](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OIW4ARVbhrw) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not a common saying, but I think the idea you want to express is conveyed by the following proverb:

***“[Never ask a barber if he thinks you need a haircut](https://www.barrypopik.com/index.php/new_york_city/entry/never_ask_a_barber_if_he_thinks_you_need_a_haircut_business_proverb/)”*** (business proverb)

> - The barber is in the business of cutting hair; he doesn’t make money if you don’t get a haircut. If you ask a sales specialist if you need to buy his particular product, he’ll always say that you do.

(www.barrypopik.com)

Comment: Why not add the Italian equivalent? *Non chiedere all'oste se il vino è buono* which if you translated into English, comes closer to hitting the nail on its head.

Comment: @AMN - thanks, but I think you should wait before accepting. More suggestions might come up.

Comment: Yes but in this instance it suited the purpose very well. Although I surely wished for a match other than from business domain.

Comment: @AMN - as suggested, the Italian, actually Neapolitan saying " *Ogni scarrafone è bello a mamma soja*" that is "*every cockroach is beautiful in the eyes of his mother* " would be a perfect fit, but I'm not sure there is anything in English  with a mother/child reference.

Answer (score 0):

As a reply to a mother's unconditional love and unwavering loyalty, one could say

> A mother's love [**knows no bounds**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/know+no+bounds)

Tell a mother her child is unattractive, a bit dim, or just plain boring, and that mother will very often leap to her child's defence.

Closely related to the idea of a parent or friend who willfully ignores a person's shortcomings is the expression: **[be blind to something](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/be-blind-to-something)**

> to completely fail to notice or realize something (LDOCE)
>
> - He also loved his daughter, and was blind to her eccentricities.
> - He was totally blind to the faults of his children.

There's also a famous saying, whose origins are perhaps Biblical,

**[there's none so deaf as those who will not hear](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/there-s-none-so-deaf-as-those-who-will-not-hear)**

said to someone who stubbornly refuses to believe what they are told

But I do like the Italian aphorism

> "**[ogni scarrafone è bello a mamma sua](https://mymemory.translated.net/en/Italian/English/ogni-scarrafone-%C3%A8-bello-a-mamma-sua%2Ftrackback%2F)**"

Which means, every mother cockroach sees her "baby" as being beautiful/special

Comment: relevant: https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/76604-delusions-are-often-functional-a-mother-s-opinions-about-her-children-s

Answer (score -5):

A hypernymic expression is:

**Beauty is in the eye of the beholder.**

> Literal meaning - the perception of beauty is subjective.
>
> Origin:
>
> This saying first appeared in the 3rd century BC in Greek. It didn't
>   appear in its current form in print until the 19th century, but in the
>   meantime there were various written forms that expressed much the same
>   thought. In 1588, the English dramatist John Lyly, in his Euphues and
>   his England, wrote:
>
> "...as neere is Fancie to Beautie, as the pricke to the Rose, as the
>   stalke to the rynde, as the earth to the roote." ...
>
> The person who is widely credited with coining the saying in its
>   current form is Margaret Wolfe Hungerford (née Hamilton), who wrote
>   many books, often under the pseudonym of 'The Duchess'. In Molly Bawn,
>   1878, there's the line "Beauty is in the eye of the beholder"

{[The Phrase Finder](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/beauty-is-in-the-eye-of-the-beholder.html)}

The broadened sense is given at [oels.byu.edu/student/idioms](http://oels.byu.edu/student/idioms/proverbs/beauty.html):

> *Beauty is in the eye of the beholder.*
>
> Meaning: You use this proverb to say that different people have
>   different opinions about what is good/beautiful/valuable [/treasured].

Comment: mmm, I think OP is referring to something different. A mother will always and only say that her child is the best. It is not a question of ***subjectivity***, but sort of ***prejudice*** here.

Comment: But [powerthesaurus](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/subjectivity) lists subjectivity (... bias ... partiality ...) and prejudice as synonyms.

Comment: This is completely wrong.